# applicationDidBecomeActive called multiple times in iOS 10

Tags: ios, core-location

In my app user location allow permission popup flashes many times at the application launch.

My code

```
AppDelegate.m 

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   [self.shareModel startMonitoringLocation];
}

LocationManager.m

- (void)startMonitoringLocation {
     if (_anotherLocationManager)
        [_anotherLocationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    self.anotherLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    _anotherLocationManager.delegate = self;
    _anotherLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
  _anotherLocationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;
    _anotherLocationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates=YES;
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [_anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [_anotherLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

In my code applicationDidBecomeActive is called multiple times and therefore locationmanager popups many times at application launch due to which my app was rejected at a recent update

```
Rejection issue:

From Apple
2. 1 PERFORMANCE: APP COMPLETENESS
Performance - 2.1


We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.0.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

Specifically, your app’s Background Location modal alert continuously appears and prevents access to the app.

Next Steps

Please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify the issue(s), then revise and resubmit your app for review.
```

I have researched for a couple of days but couldnt find the issue in iOS10.

Any ideas/suggestions would be highly helpful & very thankful

Comment: Your application will become inactive any time a system dialog (such as a permissions dialog) is shown and becomes active once that dialog is dismissed, so perhaps you should use didEnterForeground

Comment: @Paulw11 As you have said applicationDidBecomeActive is called everytime permission dialog is dismissed . But we dont have didEnterForeground in iOS and applicationWillEnterForeground is not called when permissions dialog are dismissed.Can u plz let me know how to proceed further

Comment: Why do you want to know that the permission dialog has been dismissed? If you are trying to do something after the user has responded to the location permission request, you should use the `didChangeAuthorization` location manager delegate method

Comment: @Paulw11 I dont want to know whether permission dialog has been dismissed or not.Its just that applicationDidBecomeActive is called each time after the dialog is dismissed and then again locationmanager.m code is executed , this continues for about 5-6 times and location popup goes on flashing without allowing me to click " Allow " or "Don't allow" buttons

Comment: What I am trying to understand is why you are calling `startMonitoringLocation` in `didBecomeActive`?

Comment: @Paulw11 Let me know where should I call it..My app should ask for user location at launch itself;

Comment: You should set up your location manager in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` including requesting `whenInUse` or `always` access as required.  When you get the authorisation updated call back you can start location updates

Answer (score 0):

Why not add

```
    [self.shareModel startMonitoringLocation];
```

in

```
applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

or try :

```
- (void)startMonitoringLocation {
 if (_anotherLocationManager == nil) {
self.anotherLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
_anotherLocationManager.delegate = self;
_anotherLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
_anotherLocationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;
_anotherLocationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates=YES;

if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    [_anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
[_anotherLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
} else {
    [_anotherLocationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
}
```